# Aligning adjacent elements to left, center, and right using flex?

Tags: html, css

I would like to align *HeaderNavLinks* to the left, center *Logo*, and align the remaining items *Contact*, *Mailbox*, *Language*, *Admin* to the right.

I'm actually limited to add an additional parent div for each of these elements.
Is there a way to do this? I can't seem to properly align the *Logo* at the center of the page.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container>div:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.container .center {
  align-self: center;
}

.push {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>HeaderNavLinks</div>
  <div class="center">Logo</div>
  <div class="push">Contact</div>
  <div>Mailbox</div>
  <div>Language</div>
  <div>Admin</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your example they are aligned

Comment: obviously, `Logo` is not center aligned.

Comment: It should be exactly on the middle of the page instead between of the nav and menu items?

Comment: right.. that's my issue, I need to align *Logo* at the center of the page.

Comment: you can use `position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; ` but it will not be responsive on smaller screens

Comment: so I followed your advice. and came up with this. https://codepen.io/zettainino/pen/OJPqXGy

thanks!